# Why is my code stuck in an infinite loop when scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am learning how to do basic web scraping with Python 3, and in this example I was trying to scrape all the author names from the website http://quotes.toscrape.com. I was trying to create a code where I did not know the total number of pages there were on the website. However, when I try to build it the editor does not respond. Is there a problem with the code, or should I let it run for longer?

```
import requests
import bs4
i = 0
authors = set()
while True:
    try:
        if i == 0:
            url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com"
        else: 
            url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{}/".format(i+1)
        
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        
        for name in soup.select('.author'):
            authors.add(name.text)
            
        
        i += 1
        
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Because the site always returns a valid response?

Comment: There is no condition that ends your while loop

Comment: Because you have a `while True` that does not exit unless an exception is raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to how this website will return a valid response even if there is no quotes in that page number (e.g. try http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/23400/). Therefore you will most likely never (or at least it will take a very long time to) hit any error that will cause your break statement. You should instead try to break once you reach a text like "No quotes found!", e.g.:

```
import requests
import bs4
i = 0
authors = set()
while True:
    try:
        if i == 0:
            url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com"
        else: 
            url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{}/".format(i+1)
    
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

        if "No quotes found!" in str(soup):
            break
    
        for name in soup.select('.author'):
            authors.add(name.text)
        
    
        i += 1
    
    except:
        break
```

Comment: I think, it's more reliable to verify that there are no authors/quotes on the current page.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid point @bereal. Both checking for quotes or authors will provide a good way of detecting when to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
import bs4

i = 0
authors = set()

while True:

    url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com" if i == 0 else \
         f"http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{i}/"

    res = requests.get(url)

    if res.text.find('No quotes found!') < 0:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        for name in soup.select('.author'):
            authors.add(name.text)
        i += 1
    else:
        break
```